# Hiring a Ferrari in Italy

Tags: car-rentals, italy, mountains, luxury

I am planning a trip to Italy, and would like to hire a Ferrari for a day. I am aware that this will be expensive.

What should I watch out for? When the deductible is 80,000 Euros, I'd assume it's probably a good idea to purchase a deductible reduction, and also good ideas to not park on the street in big cities and to never let the car out of my sight.

Assume for this question that I'd like to drive on some mountain roads. Where would be the best place to hire one? Milan? Modena? Verona?

Comment: For how many days?

Comment: I was thinking just one day, due to the monumental cost. If longer periods mean cheaper, great! A week would be nice if it didn't bankrupt me.

Answer (score 15):

I'd want to hire it as far from busy big cities as possible.  The idea of damaging one, even if insured, would be so upsetting.

So to maximise this, you'd want to do it during term time (kids in school, less people on holiday), when there's good weather.

You'll want to pick up the car outside of rush hour, so around 10am, and still have a couple of hours to get out of town before the lunch time rush starts.

The best mountains are in the north, bordering with Switzerland.  The lakes are there too, for some different scenery.

[image]

This from [an Italian luxury car hire website](http://europeluxurycarhire.com/rent-luxury-cars-italy/ferrari-rental):

> Every region in this beautiful, boot-shaped country is different form[sic]
>   the other. To hire a Ferrari in Italy will enable you to reach
>   everyone[sic] of those regions in elegance and style. If you are in North
>   Italy, looking for a car rental in Milan, rent one of our Ferrari cars
>   and drive along snow-caped[sic] mountains, beautiful lakes (Garda, Como and
>   Maggiore) and fascinating amusement parks. Don't forget to drive your
>   Ferrari to Bergamo, Verona and Venice! In the center of Italy you can
>   hire a Ferrari in Florence and tour Tuscany, including Bologna and
>   Pisa. This route will be dotted with green forests, round hills and
>   small towns that time hasn't touched. You can rent a car in the South
>   of Italy, and drive through delightful beaches, deep blue sea scenes
>   and enchanting islands.

Incidentally that  site does quotes, but I couldn't bring myself to look, so I'll leave that bit up to you ;)

Comment: I looked for you. "Prices start from one thousand euros per day".